# Exception in Selenium webdriver(IE) in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Below is my python code,

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
print("brower1\n")
browser = webdriver.Ie('C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe')
print("brower2\n")
```

I am getting exception in `webdriver.Ie()` ,after that `print` statement `print("brower2")` is not executing....

Mentioned Below is my exception error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "automated_vpn.py", line 8, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Ie('C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.ex
e')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\ie\we
bdriver.py", line 91, in __init__
    self.iedriver.start()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\commo
n\service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\commo
n\service.py", line 109, in assert_process_still_running
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service C:\Program Files
 (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
```

please help me out for this issue...

Comment: ** IE version : 11**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webdriver should be a driver path for the corresponding browser. IE driver files can be found [here](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).

I'd recommed you download the 32-bit IE Driver file, unzip it and place the executable in your program folder and link it like:

```
browser = webdriver.Ie("C:\\Script path\\IEDriverServer.exe")
```

Now when you run the script, it should open IE browser.

Answer (score 1):

The path should have double slash or it should have a leading r like
r"c:\Program Files(x86)\file.exe"

But the path supplied should be of IE webdriver server and not internet explorer. Download from [here](https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html) and add the path to your environment path variable or supply the full path. This drivers in the mentioned link has been tested with IE 7, 8, 9, 10, and 11 on appropriate combinations of Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8, and Windows 8.1. The 3.9 version of the server is fairly stable but, the latest driver is always recommended. So, it should be

```
browser = webdriver.Ie(executable_path=r'C:\Python27\IEDriverServer.exe')
```

The path to IEDriverServer.exe should be included in path.

Now this will work only if

1. You have same protected mode settings for all internet zones in
   internet explorer. It can be on or off but has to be same for all
   zones.
2. For IE11 only, there must be a registry value present. For 32-bit Windows 
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet
   Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE. For 64-bit Windows
   installations, the key is
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet
   Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE. Please note that the
   FEATURE_BFCACHE subkey may or may not be present, and should be
   created if it is not present. Important: Inside this key, create a
   DWORD value named iexplore.exe with the value of 0.
3. There are known issues with 64 bit IEDriver server, so it is recommended that you use 
   32 bit server which will automatically launch 32 bit IE browser.

All these requirements are explained [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver).